# Camera position w.r.t. basketball court

Tags: computer-vision

I am new in Computer Vision. Suppose you have 8 points (players in a basketball court) in a 2D image (png photo), that is we know the pixel coordinates of each. I would like to compute camera position w.r.t. the field. We have the actual dimensions of the field. Also, I can write the equations of two or three transversal lines in the field that are parallels lines from top view. With this data can we find a position vector of the camera w.r.t. the field ?

> Any idea on where to read about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you could see lines, so I assume you could see their intersections. If you could assume to have at least 4 fixed points of the court which are always visible (corners might be a good choice), this problem is similar to the [3D pose estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_pose_estimation) problem, since you are essentially looking for a pose (position and orientation) of a known 3D object in a 2D image.

You might find it useful to read about POSIT, an iterative algorithm [published](http://www.cfar.umd.edu/~daniel/daniel_papersfordownload/Pose25Lines.pdf) in 1992 and there is also [this](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00590105/document) algorithm from 1999. Both algorithm solve the 3D pose estimation problem.